# Неизвестный оператор. (near "WITH" at position 0)

Tags: mysql, sql

Возникает ошибка при попытке использовать with в панели phpMyAdmin, как я понимаю phpMyAdmin использует MySQL, а в нем есть with, но вот у меня он никак его не воспринимает.

```
   WITH Tree
    AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM data 
    )
   SELECT * FROM Tree
```

Ошибка

```
    Статический анализ:

Найдено 1 ошибок при анализе.

    Неизвестный оператор. (near "WITH" at position 0)

SQL запрос: Документация

WITH Tree AS ( SELECT * FROM data ) SELECT * FROM Tree

Ответ MySQL: Документация
#1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'Tree
    AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM data
    )
   SELECT * FROM Tree' на строке 1
```

Comment: with есть в MySQL только с 8 версии. А 8 версия пока еще мало где стоит и подозреваю что у вас 5я

Comment: просто я пользовался статьей с инструкцией 2015 года, 4 года прошло, а 8 версия так и не доехала до народных масс?

Comment: Нет, не доехала и еще лет 5 будет ехать ...

Comment: И `select @@version` действительно дает 8.0 ?

Comment: короче в 8 версии так же подсвечивает ошибку, но код выполняет, все нормально, почти

Comment: ну это уже phpmyadmin до сих пор не готов к этому и зачем то делает свой собственный разбор sql